# Migrate Django project from PyCharm to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm

I'm looking to migrate my Django project from PyCharm to VsCode, it has source control with github and I'm on a mac. I've looked around, however, I've not come across a step by step guide. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there should be any problem as this is just a shift from an IDE to a text editor.

Pycharm maybe creating virtual env automatically for you which now you need to do manually but if you didnot changed anything, the virtual env will also be there.

For github, use git shell or cmd to make changes.

Rest is just codinggg